# Does JDesktopPane.getAllFrames() always indicate JInternalFrame z order?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktop

I could not find it in any documentation, but as far as I found out experimental calling `getAllFrames()` returns all internal frames *exactly* in their z order.

Does anyone know if this observation is always true or can give any reference for it?

Comment: the api is _the_ reference, nothing else. If it doesn't mention the sequence, then it's unspecified and may freely change across implementations/versions. Why do you want to know, what requirement do you want to satify based on your (accidental!) observation?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if this observation is always true

I would say yes.

> or can give any reference for it?

Look at the source code for the `getAllFrames()` method. It just iterates through all the components in the container. And since the components are always in ZOrder when you do this iteration the returned array will be in ZOrder.

Comment: Yes.. but if that is not mentioned in the Java Docs, another VM (or a different version of the same VM) might do it differently.  AFAIU, if it is not explicitly stated in the docs., there is no guarantee.

Comment: agree with @AndrewThompson everything that's not documented is an implemenation detail, may differ across different implementations and change without notice - don't rely on them in production code